# Count variables with same name with auto increment

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, count

I´m still new in php and I´m having trouble in sending a form vars through POST.
I use a jquery to dynamically add new fields with the same name plus a auto increment ID in a form.

In the _POST I need to have a loop to get those vars, but how am I going to get the vars count for the loop?

I have something like this:

```
$ID1_name = $_POST["ID1_name"];
$ID2_name = $_POST["ID2_name"];
$ID3_name = $_POST["ID3_name"];
$IDX_name = $_POST["IDX_name"];

$ID1_place = $_POST["ID1_place"];
$ID2_place = $_POST["ID2_place"];
$ID3_place = $_POST["ID3_place"];
$IDX_place = $_POST["IDX_place"];
```

There can be unlimited variables with same name with and AI, and I have around 10 vars like that.

How can I count by the var partial name?
or
Is there a better way to get those _POST? I´m using a For loop.

I was using the same name and counting in the array. It worked, but I have 3 fields with radio and 2 with checkbox, and in the array all the vars of the same name merge. So the array for food have entries from all food checkbox from the field. Does that make sense?

So in one $ID1_place = string  I might have $ID1_check = array

Thanks for the help. I´know there is a easy way, but I think I´m searching the wrong way since I found nothing.

Thanks a lot.
regards

Comment: Have jQuery serialise it as `ID[1][name]=foo&ID[1][place]=bar&...`; it will make your life a whole lot easier.

Comment: just create a grouping name so that its easier to manage them once they are being used in your PHP, just like the comment above ^

Comment: Thanks guys, I just read the Jquery serialise manual and I´m going to try implement. It sounds a simple and effective way. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks guys. I used Jquery to count one field that is added. But I will eventually use the Jquery serialise. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways I can think for this. Either you can pass through a hidden element with the number of elements with your name, or you can use the `preg_grep` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) to match all `POST` vars matching a regex pattern:

```
// Search keys:
$ID_place_keys = preg_grep('/ID[0-9]+_place/', array_keys($_POST));

// Search values:
$ID_places = preg_grep('/ID[0-9]+_place/', $_POST);

// Get array of values matching keys:
$ID_places = array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip(preg_grep('/ID[0-9]+_place/', array_keys($_POST))));
// Gets a bit messy with all the array functions...
```

And here's a URL to a simple working example:

http://ideone.com/a9AhL6

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I´ve tried the `preg_grep` function. But  it seems it searches for the array content only, not the var name. When I use the way you showed it returns an empty array. If I use only numbers in the serch, it returns the vars that contains numbers and in that case several different vars.

Comment: I managed to use a hidden field that counts, using JQuery, the number of the specified field. Thanks a lot. The preg_grep will be useful in other codes. Without your help I would not know what to look for.

Comment: Sorry that my `preg_grep` example was bad. You could have still used `preg_grep` in combination with `array_keys`. I have added to my answer an example

Comment: Thanks a lot man, It worked like a charm, and I got to read more about the array_keys and others functions and going to use it for sure later on. Thank you very much for the time and patience to help and demonstrate. My best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered instead of sending a lot of post variables, to send only two; where all the fields are json encoded?

**Example:** `names: ["ID1", "ID2", "ID3"]` and `places: ["ID1", "ID2", "ID3"]`. To get the AJAX parameters like this you can stringify the arrays you have using `JSON.stringify()`. Ref: [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Then on the back-end just do `$names = json_decode($_POST["names"])` and `$places = json_decode($_POST["places"])`

This way you have an array with the id-s of the names and places. You can count them, loop over them, do whatever you need to.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I have´t used the JSON.stringfy() but in the future I will use it for sure. I´ll change the way to send the data and JSON will be the choice. Thanks for help.

Comment: Sure, tell me if you need any further assistance with that solution.

Comment: Thank you very much, for your time and patience to help.